# Topological charge change in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topology, vortex, instantons, solitons

Is it possible for the topological charge to change in quantum field theory?
The proofs in the following paper: [Quantum soliton operators for vortices and superselection rules](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.18.2091)

are all based on the assumption that operators appearing in the Lagrangian have compact support.

I was wondering what if one can include terms in the lagrangian that appear only on the boundary of space and vanish in the bulk.

Is it possible to evade the superselection rules in such a case by means of tunneling between the otherwise topologically distinct (asymptotically vacuum) states via the new boundary term?

For sure the term should be divergent by nature, but for me, that's not a great source of pain as chances are that the divergence can be renormalized in the final result though I've no candidate and it's purely speculative idea. But honestly, I thought very stupidly that there's already a source of infinity in the Hamiltonian in every non-interacting QFT due to the vacuum state.

Does anyone know any case that is close to this scenario?